# TwistedWeb: Custom 404 Not Found pages

Tags: python, twisted, twisted.web

I am quite surprised I couldn't find anything on this in my Google searching.

I'm using TwistedWeb to make a simple JSON HTTP API.  I'd like to customize the 404 page so it returns something in JSON rather than the default HTML.  How might I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API in Twisted Web like `something.set404(someResource)`.  A *NOT FOUND* response is generated as the default when resource traversal reaches a point where the next child does not exist - as indicated by the next `IResource.getChildWithDefault` call.  Depending on how your application is structured, this means you may want to have your own base class implementing `IResource` which creates your custom *NOT FOUND* resource for all of its subclasses (or, better, make a wrapper since composition is better than inheritance).

If you read the implementation of `twisted.web.resource.Resource.getChild` you'll see where the default *NOT FOUND* behavior comes from and maybe get an idea of how to create your own similar behavior with different content.

Comment: I guess it's simple enough to roll my own, but I do wish there was an API for it.